# How to use a variable as the substitution text in perl (s//)?

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I want to use a variable as the substitution text in perl (s//)? Apparently, the following code does not work. Is there a way to do what I want?

```
~$  ./subsuffix.pl 
xxx_$1_outsuffix.txt
```

subsuffix.pl :

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename="xxx_5p_insuffix.txt";
my $insuffix="_((5|3)p)_insuffix.txt";
my $outsuffix = '_$1_outsuffix.txt';

#result of the following is what I expect
#$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/_$1_outsuffix.txt/;
#But I want used a variable as the substitution text. 
#Unfortunately, the following do not work.
$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/$outsuffix/;
print "$filename\n";
```

Comment: Side note: You can also declare $insuffix as `my $insuffix= qr{_((5|3)p)_insuffix.txt$};`. Note that the ending $ anchor is already in here instead of being in the regex later. This would help if you are going to use the regex several times.

Answer (score 4):

The replacement is normally not evaluated. You have to add a couple of `/e`'s at the end of the substitution and add some quotes to keep it a valid expression after the 1st evaluation:

```
$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/qq("$outsuffix")/ee;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `/e` modifier to treat the substitution pattern as code to be evaluated:

```
$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/ "_" . $1 . "_outsuffix.txt" /e;
```

Answer (score 2):

What you have in `$outsuffix` is a template. Templates don't magically process themselves. You'll need to invoke a processor. [String::Interpolate](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?String%3a%3aInterpolate) understands templates such as yours.

```
use String::Interpolate qw( interpolate );

my $filename="xxx_5p_insuffix.txt";
my $insuffix="_((5|3)p)_insuffix.txt";
my $outsuffix = '_$1_outsuffix.txt';

$filename =~ s/$insuffix$/interpolate($outsuffix)/e;
print "$filename\n";
```